# Form_to @object Routing issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I have a custom route pointing to a method in my controller to update part of view, but I'm getting a routing error.

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Exams#show
Showing /home/tom/rails/oplei/app/views/exams/_quiz.html.erb where line #12 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"answer_problem_path", :id=>"102", :controller=>"exams"}
```

My custom route is as follows:

```
  resources :exams do
    get 'answer_problem'
  end
```

And this should be pointing to a method in my Exams controller.

app/controllers/exams_controller:

```
  def answer_problem
    @answered = @facts[params[:fIndex].to_i]
    if @answered.id == params[:answer].to_i
      #answered correctly
      @resultText = "Correct!"
    else
      #incorrect answer
      @resultText = "Incorrect :("
    end

    #@currentFact = @facts[@answered.id + 1]
    @currentFact = @facts[params[:fIndex].to_i + 1]

    if @currentFact == @facts.last
      @endOfArray = 'yes'      
    else
      @endOfArray = 'no'
    end

    @choices = Fact.where(question_type: @currentFact.question_type).where.not(id: @currentFact.id).
                order('RANDOM()').limit(3)
    @choices.push(@currentFact)
    @choices.shuffle!
  end
```

(I know, this action has major refactoring in store for it.)

I'll be calling this with the following form_for:

```
<%= form_for(@exam, url: {action: 'exam_answer_problem_path'}, remote: true) do |f| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'answer', choice.id %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'fIndex', @facts.index(@currentFact) %>
    <%= f.submit choice.answer, class: "btn btn-default btn-answer", id: "answerButton" %>
<% end %>
```

After a couple of hours playing with it, I still can't quite figure out where this routing error is coming from and I haven't even gotten to the form_for to see what kind of problems I'll have there, is there a different way to do this?

Comment: try rake routes and find the matching routes and put where you required.

Answer (score 0):

See section 2.10.1 of http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web to understand the results of your routes declaration. In your case, the path `answer_problem_exam_path` was defined as a result of your routes declaration, but you're trying to use `answer_problem_path`.